# The sentence meaning - found + unfulfilling

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

What does the following sentence mean exactly?

> The United States dancer Loie Fuller (1862–1928) **found** theatrical
>   dance in the late nineteenth century artistically 
>   **unfulfilling**.

Is the "found" here past tense of "find"? Or it is the verb "found"?

What is the meaning of "unfulfilling" precisely in the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **found** is the past tense of the verb "to find". The past tense of the verb "to found" is **founded**.

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fulfilling) says about **fulfilling**:

> ADJECTIVE
>   Making someone satisfied or happy through allowing their character or abilities to develop fully.
>   *a fulfilling and rewarding career*

So the sentence means

> Loie Fuller's experience of theatrical dance in the late nineteenth century was artistically unsatisfying.